# Image fill parent div width and height wise, and center

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am loading a rather large image into the parent div and my `pug` code is as follows:

```
a.eventlist-column-thumbnail.content-fill(href=`${link}`)
    img(src=`${img_src}`, alt=`${img_src}`, style='position: static; float:left; width: 100%;')
```

The point here is that with `width: 100%` I am able to fill the parent w/ the following effect:

[image: rand-walk-2.png]

This isn't bad however as you look closely, you'll see that the image does not fill the height, because aspect ratio wise it is "skinnier" than the parent div.

I would like to achieve this effect where the image fills the width and height as `conservatively` as possible while remaining centered relative to parent div:

[image: rand-walk-3.png]

Not very familiar with `html/css`, so please give pointers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set `width: 100%;` and fixed height - in pixels: `height: --px;`

— — https://jsfiddle.net/ge5o91vg/4/

Comment: the issue is this I will be loading lots of different sizes of images, so it's not really possible to come up w/ a generic one.

Answer (score -1):

try `object-fit: cover;` in img tag

Comment: The images come out in different sizes, depending on the size of the original image.